# Forbidden 403 when trying to access metrics for monetized channels

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

I'm looking for a way to test obtaining `estimatedRevenue` from the reporting api

```
https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?metrics=estimatedRevenue&startDate=2005-01-01&endDate=2022-08-03&ids=channel==MINE
```

I am getting the proper permissions via the OAuth 2.0 api via

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-content-owner-readonly&access_type=offline&response_type=code&include_granted_scopes=true&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&client_id={client_id}
```

but the api is returning

```
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Forbidden",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm assuming this is because the channel I'm testing with doesn't have monetization enabled? If so is there a way to simulate a channel with monetization turned on so I can test getting estimatedRevenue metrics?

Answer (score 0):

First off im not exactly sure what method you are calling. in the [YouTube Analytics api.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs.reports/get)

> Forbidden

means you do not have permission.

```
GET https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs/[JOBID]/reports/[REPORTID]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

Make sure you have applied the access token properly.